# Coding a simple SHARED Button for Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, button, share

Which of the 2 ways am I supposed to use to create a simple share button for Facebook in my game app?

1) import Social Framework into project and then put in the following code...

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [controller setInitialText:@"High score is %i"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];        
}
```

2) Add Facebook SDK into your project, get a Facebook App ID by signing up to Facebook's developer program, then add App ID into .plist file, link FBSDKShareKit.framework  into project and then use the code provided by Facebook (and there's a LOT of it).

The 1st way of doing it works perfectly fine. Is it a MUST for me to do it the 2nd way? If I do it the first way, would I get in trouble with Facebook or would Apple reject my app? Also, if I do it the first way does it mean I can't use the Facebook "f" logo for the Facebook SHARE button?

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on sharing OpenGraph Stories within your game I would go with the Facebook SDK. According to [Facebook's official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#ios-integration):

"iOS 6+ includes a native share sheet that lets people post status updates, photos, videos and links to Facebook and includes support for setting the audience for the post and tagging the post with a location. You cannot share Open Graph Stories with the share sheet. The Facebook SDK supports the use of this native controller.

While you can use the iOS native view controller API (share sheet) directly, there are several reasons to use the native iOS Share dialog provided by the Facebook SDK. Using the native Share dialog provides a quick way to test that people have signed into Facebook on their iOS 6+ devices"

If you need more information to decide, I suggest you take a look at [Sharing on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)